# How can I ensure that no null value is assigned to a variable using Perl grep function?

Tags: perl

How to put value into a scalar variable when using Perl's [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) method?

For example, I have the following code and need to put the value from the per grep method into a scalar variable?

```
        my $variable = grep(/@/,@dataRecord);
```

Answer (score 3):

if you mean `grep` return 1 element than

```
my ($variable) = grep(/@/,@dataRecord);
```

else you should use arrayref

```
my $variable = [ grep(/@/,@dataRecord) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one of the matching elements of `@dataRecord`, using [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) might not be the most appropriate choice. That is because `grep` will check all elements no matter how many matches you want to extract.

You have to first decide which of the potentially more than one matching elements in `@dataRecord` you want. If you want the first matching element, you'd be better off using [List::MoreUtils::firstval](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List%3a%3aMoreUtils):

> ```
> firstval BLOCK LIST
> first_value BLOCK LIST
> ```
>
> Returns the first element in LIST for which BLOCK evaluates to true. Each element of LIST is set to `$_` in turn. Returns undef if no such element has been found.